# What is VARYING?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, function, functional-programming

I was recently reading a Microsoft page regarding cursor data type.
And I read the following:

"Transact-SQL stored procedures can use the cursor data type only for OUTPUT parameters. If the cursor data type is specified for a parameter, both the VARYING and OUTPUT parameters are required. If the VARYING keyword is specified for a parameter, the data type must be cursor and the OUTPUT keyword must be specified."

What exactly is the "VARYING" or what that means???

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [CREATE PROCEDURE documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

> "**VARYING** Specifies the result set supported as an output
>   parameter. This parameter is dynamically constructed by the procedure
>   and its contents may vary. Applies only to cursor parameters. This
>   option is not valid for CLR procedures."

The `VARYING` keyword is simply a part of the syntax when you specify a parameter of the type `CURSOR`.

The keyword is supposedly chosen as the result returned in the parameter isn't specified, and the layout of the result can vary without breaking the definition. In contrast, a parameter of `TABLE` type (input only) has a defined layout.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

"cursor  data types can only be OUTPUT parameters and must be accompanied by the VARYING keyword"

So it is just a syntax requirement.